# search query using jsoup

Tags: java, jquery, jsoup

I want to perform search an item using jsoup using this link, for example i want to find powerbank

http://www.mudah.my/li?frmsrch=1&fs=1&ca=9_s&cg=0&w=3&so=1&st=s&q=powerbank

and i want jsoup to extract and provide output what powerbank that available like image below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ej04s.png)

```
  String SEARCH_STRING = "powerbank";
    String URL = "http://www.lazada.com.my/catalog/?q=";


    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL + SEARCH_STRING)
            .referrer(URL + SEARCH_STRING).get();
```

can anyone help me? thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check it.

```
Elements elements = doc.select("li div.product-description");

for (Element element : elements) {

    String title = element.select("a.product-name").first().attr("title");  
    String img = element.select("img").first().attr("src");
    String href = element.select("a").first().attr("href"); 
    String priceNormal = element.select("span.product-price-normal").first().text();    
    String priceDiscount = element.select("span.product-price-discount").isEmpty() ? "-" : element.select("span.product-price-discount").first().text();    
    String priceDiscountPercent = element.select("div.product-discount").isEmpty() ? "0" : element.select("div.product-discount").first().text();

}
```

Comment: oh thanks but how to extract each of title ? thank  you very much

Comment: Thank you so much! @Hasanaga

Comment: Good luck. @NisaAsilaMN

Comment: Btw @Hasanaga i have another question, for this kind of url http://www.mudah.my/li?frmsrch=1&fs=1&ca=9_s&cg=0&w=3&so=1&st=s&q=powerbank where need to extract

Comment: which should i select for that url, Elements elements = doc.select("li div.product-description");

Comment: `Elements elements = doc.select("div.list_ads");
 for (Element element : elements) {
  
  String img = element.select("div.thumbnail_images img").first().attr("abs:src");
  String href = element.select("div.thumbnail_images a").first().attr("abs:href");  String title = element.select("h2.list_title.truncate").first().text(); }`

Comment: may i ask one more thing for url http://www.mudah.my/li?frmsrch=1&fs=1&ca=9_s&cg=0&w=3&so=1&st=s&q=powerbank, i want to extract the price, why when i put this coding String price = element.select("div.ads_price").first().text(); it doesnt give any output

Comment: can you please help, may i ask one more thing for url mudah.my/…, i want to extract the price, why when i put this coding String price = element.select("div.ads_price").first().text(); it doesnt give any output

Comment: I did try, but It Worked for me `String price = element.select("div.ads_price").first().text();`